# react native plugin to integrate amazon polly or lex

Tags: react-native, audio-streaming, amazon-lex, amazon-polly

I am trying to integrate amazon lex in react native app, text api worrks fine but i am not able to stream audio to lex streaming api.

i tried react-native-audio-toolkit and react-native-fetch-blob plugins with no luck, any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,